# Deep merge of complex state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I have the following initial state declared:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isValid: false,
      metaData: {
        age: 12,
        content_type: 'short_url'
      }
    };
  },
```

and I update state with `setState` like this:

```
...
let newMetaData = {  age: 20 };
...
this.setState({
        isValid: true,
        metaData: newMetaData
      });
...
```

Resulting `this.state.metadata` object has only age defined. But as far as I'm aware, `this.setState()` merges it argument to existing state. Why it's not working here, isn't this supposed to be recurrent merging?

**Is there a way to merge new object properties to state object property in React/ES6?**

Comment: ES6 spread operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) performs a shallow merge. If metaData is is flat:

```
this.setState({
  metaData: Object.assign({}, this.state.metaData, newMetaData),
});
```

or if using spread :

```
this.setState({
  metaData: { ...this.state.metaData, ...newMetaData },
});
```

Comment: The spread operator merge isn't a "deep" merge, meaning merges are recursive. Moreover nested object properties aren't merged

REF: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-deep-merge

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this, if you only need to update one property, would be like this:

```
this.setState({
  metaData: {
    ...this.state.metaData,
    age: 20
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

setState can also take a function, which receives an argument of state, and you can use lodash merge to do the deep merge.

```
  setState(state => merge(state, yourPartialObjectToBeDeepMerged));
```

Answer (score 0):

a tricky solution is here

```js
const [complexObject, setComplexObject] = useState({a:{b:{c:1}}})
setComplexObject((s)=>{
  s.a.b.c = 2
  return {...s}
})
```

How does it work?

An object is a reference. If you `s.a.b.c = 2`, this will update the state, but the component doesn't rerender, so the dom will not change.

Then we need a way to rerender the component. If you `setComplexObject(s=>s)`, it will not trigger rerender, because albeit the interior of the ComplexObject do change, the reference still point at the same object.

So we need ES6 spread operator to reconstruct a object by doing this `{...s}`