# Update array of object in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update question name on `onChange` event. But problem is every question changes if I change only one ques.How to fix it ?

```
class QuestionCreate extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datas: [],
            default_question: {
                isNew: true,
                question: {
                    name: 'Click to write the question text',
                    answer_options: [
                        {name: 'click to write choice 1', 'choice': true},
                        {name: 'click to write choice 1', 'choice': true},
                        {name: 'click to write choice 1', 'choice': true},
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    }


    onChangeQuestion(qustions, index, event){
        let all_data = this.state.datas;
        let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question
        all_data[index]['question']['name'] = event.target.value;
        console.log(all_data[index]['question']['name'])
        this.setState({datas: all_data})

    }

    displayRow(){
    let rowData = this.state.datas.map( (data, index) =>{
        console.log("this is data:", data, index);
        return(
            <div className="well" key={ index }>
                <h3>Q. <input type="text" onChange={ this.onChangeQuestion.bind(this, data, index) } value={ data.question.name } /></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>option</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return rowData;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put this code in Fiddle or Codepen or Plunker?

Comment: Please post your initial data and what data you are getting after operation.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/584x2qg1/. I have put it in js fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating your state directly.

```
let all_data = this.state.datas;
let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question
all_data[index]['question']['name'] = event.target.value;
```

Use:

```
let all_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.datas));
let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question;
all_data[index]['question']['name'] = event.target.value;
this.setState({datas: all_data});
```

These questions may also be helpful.

- [Deep merge of complex state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601834/deep-merge-of-complex-state-in-react)
- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074)

Comment: You are changing `this.state` by using the above statements. This is not good. You can read https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important to better understand the issue.

Comment: Do ask if you still have any doubts

Comment: onChangeQuestion(qustions, index, event){
  let all_data = this.state.datas;
  let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question
  let newQues = Object.assign({}, currentQuestion, {name:event.target.value})
  this.setState({
   datas: all_data
  })
  
 }

Comment: is there need this line ? this.setState({ datas: all_data })

Comment: in the line `let all_data = this.state.datas;`, you are assigning a reference to `this.state.datas`. So when you change `all_data`, you change `this.state`. In order to avoid that, you can do `let all_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.datas));` to create a copy of `this.state.datas`.

Comment: this is not working. Please modify and give me exact code of `onChangeQuestion` method

Comment: Yes you need the this.setState(). State should be changed only using setState, so that your components are updated correctly based on the new state.

Comment: let all_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.datas));
let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question
all_data[index]['question']['name'] = event.target.value;
this.setState({datas: all_data});

Comment: yes now working but why it needs to convert  JSON to string?

Comment: It is a little hack to create a copy of an object, without mutating the original object. First convert to string using JSON.stringify. Then convert to object using JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

it is working after editing `onChangeQuestion` function.

```
onChangeQuestion(qustions, index, event){
    let all_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.datas)); 
    let currentQuestion = all_data[index].question 
    all_data[index]['question']['name'] = event.target.value; 
    this.setState({datas: all_data});
}
```