# How to add a object to state of react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I have `object={x:[],y:[],z:[]}` got from Api and passed it as prop from `<Acomponent/>` to child `<Bcomponent/>` like `<Acomponent data={object}/>`.

`<Bcomponent/>` state is `{a:[],b:[],c:[]}`
I want data props from `<Acomponent>` to be added to state of `<Bcomponent/>`

(i.e) final state of `<Bcomponent/>` has to be

```
{a:[],b:[],c:[],x:[],y:[],z:[]}
```

How it can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601834/deep-merge-of-complex-state-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use constructor

```
class Bcomponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                a: [],
                b: [],
                c: [],
                x: props.data.x,
                y: props.data.y,
                z: props.data.z
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

or `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object spread syntax to merge objects:

```
class Bcomponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const {data} = props;

        this.state = {
            a: [],
            b: [],
            c: [],
            ...data,
        }
    }

    // ...other functions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
 a: [], b: [], c: [], ...this.props.data
};
```

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/q30w3q97r9